# how to update field with existing one on mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

i'm traing to create a goindex but before i nead to merge 2 differents field into on array i try using this code but

```
db.contenuti.update( {},
     {$set:
        { "luogo.cordinate":[luogo.dd_latitudine,luogo.dd_longitudine] },
    { "multi": true })
```

if i run the code inside the console no error appare but the 3 dot remain.

example of the page:

```
   "_id": ObjectId("534ce491e7fbe396208079b4"),
   "id_contenuto": NumberInt(188),
   "id_formato": NumberInt(19),
   "titolo": "panorama",
   "uri_cover": "http:\/\/www.inmedialoci.polito.it\/media\/img\/27032014panorama.jpg",
   "utilizzo": NumberInt(0),
   "data_caricamento": "2014-03-27T12:19:12+0100",
   "utente": {
     "id_utente": NumberInt(1),
     "nome": "Amministratore",
     "cognome": "In Media Loci" 
  },
   "luogo": {
     "id_luogo": NumberInt(9),
     "id_area": NumberInt(1),
     "nome": "Passerano Marmorito",
     "dd_latitudine"▼: 45.0545372,
     "dd_longitudine": 8.0194042,

  },
   "categorie": {
     "0": {
       "id_categoria": "4",
       "nome": "Ricordi",
       "main": "1" 
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are trying to update **cordinate** field with already available field **dd_latitudine** and **dd_longitudine** as an array. In update this same time read and write approach will not work . Easy to to achieve this is first get document and then modify it and save.

```
db.contenuti.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.luogo.cordinate = [doc.luogo.dd_latitudine,doc.luogo.dd_longitudine] ;
  db.contenuti.save(doc);
});
```